# java.io.IOException: Premature EOF

Tags: java

I am trying to download an xml file using Stream and things was fine , until the xml size became bigger than 9 MB , so i've got this error 
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF

this is the code

```
BufferedInputStream bfi = null;
        try {
            bfi = new BufferedInputStream(new URL("The URL").openStream());
            String name = "name.xml";
            FileOutputStream fb = new FileOutputStream(name);
            BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fb, 1024);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int x = 0;
            while ((x = bfi.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
                bout.write(data, 0, x);
            }
            this.deletePhishTankDatabase(this.recreateFileName());
            ptda.insertDownloadTime(hour, day, month, year);
            bout.close();
            bfi.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PhishTankDataBase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                bfi.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PhishTankDataBase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("You can't do anything");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Which line is pointed at as the cause of the Exception? You shouldn't omit useful information such as this!

Comment: @polygenelubricants: You kidding? Having us guess is the best part!

Comment: Did you look at your data and see if it had any invalid characters in it ? You might want to simplify your code and get rid of anything that does not pertain to the streams. Try echoing your input to an output  file and see what you get.

Comment: Is it at all possible there is an EOF _character_ in your XML file? Or perhaps some encoding problem? Or is the large data file just 2 slightly smaller files (which work) concatenated?

Answer (score 1):

Try using chunked streaming mode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that your application runs faster than it retrieves input data

Comment: Read blocks until data or EOS arrives.